# Unable to upload pictures to the server in the same application that captured them

Tags: android, http-post, android-image

Initially on clicking the camera button the image is being captured, displays the save and discard buttons. On clicking save it gets saved in the the specified folder, but the saved image is not being uploaded into the server.

Here is my code:

```
public class FldrActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 0;
    InputStream inputStream;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image");
        boolean success = false;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        String path = folder + "/example.jpg";

        //String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image/example2.jpg";
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

        startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE ); 

        String pathToOurFile = "/sdcard/image/example.jpg";

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToOurFile);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream); 

        //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file",image_str));

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.xyz.com/image/connection.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + the_string_response,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch(Exception {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(),
                                                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
    }

    public String convertResponseToString(HttpResponse response) throws  IllegalStateException, IOException {
        String res = "";
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength(); //getting content length…..
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "contentLength : " + contentLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (contentLength < 0) {
        }
        else {
            byte[] data = new byte[512];
            int len = 0;

            try {
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) ) {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len)); //converting to string and appending  to stringbuffer…..
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                inputStream.close(); // closing the stream…..
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            res = buffer.toString();     // converting stringbuffer to string…..

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result : " + res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //System.out.println("Response => " +  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```